# REST API returning object after POST

Tags: php, rest, post, yii2, http-post

I am creating a REST API and am currently facing a dilemma about return value after a successful POST request to my API.

Objects I am working with are the following:

- `Service` (some service that is requested by user);
- `ServicePriceSelection` (prices offered for the Service);
- `Booking` (Service *with defined price* that has been paid for).

After user POSTs object data to `/api/service` not only new `Service` object is created, but also The `ServicePriceSelection`. The user needs the data contained in `ServicePriceSelection` to display the prices and other information.

So the question which of the following would be the correct way to handle the situation:

1. Return status 201 and resource IDs of new `Service` and `ServicePriceSelection`. User would need to make GET request to `/api/service/{id}` and `/api/service/service-price-selection/{id}` to get the data.
2. Return status 201 and resource ID of new `Service` and resource ID and all data for new `ServicePriceSelection`. User would not need to make another request to get the data, but I am not sure if this is correct based on RESTful principles.

Server side programming language - PHP (Yii2 framework).

Comment: Is `ServicePriceSelection` a logical child of `Service`? If it is return the entire object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, do stuff in a way that is easier for the client. No need to make life harder for the sake of principles (to some reasonable extent).

In my personal opinion, crucial in RESTful for POST is creating elements, creating new element for each request (in contrast to idempotent PUT) and proper return code. I am flexible in anything else.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would recommend to use less non-200 html states, since the behaviour of many frontends is inadequate in that case.
2. The choice of 1 and 2 is dectated by the logics of the REST consumer (frontend). What I mean.
   2.1. After POST request, the frontend can push the user to service/{id} or some other page. In this case there is no use to send excessive data. Send just id's.
   2.2. After POST the consumer treats the response data. In this case it is worth sending the desired objects. BUT

But keep in mind, that the frontend had much data even before the POST and duplication the data in the response is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you. I have decided to allow user to POST and additional parameter that indicates whether they also want to receive new `ServicePriceSelection` data in addition to new IDs. This will not duplicate data and give user option to receive only the data they need at that point.